# Android Q - StackOverflowError when executing AsyncTask on executor

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-10.0

I have code that didn't change in the last 5 years and was working fine - I started seeing recently `StackOverflowError` in **Fabric/Firebase Crashlytics** - all the errors come from Android 10 devices.

I have a custom `AsyncTask` and it is activated using `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, data);`
`data` is a simple object in my app.

I'm not posting my custom task b/c I think that the error is generated by android internals.

this line causes this stack trace

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1386)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:711)

[image]

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe see the "Rejected Task" heading [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor).

Comment: I suggest you to migrate from AsyncTask to coroutines, rxjava or handler thread because AsyncTask soon will be deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Recent Android OS optimizations put restrictions on background operations/tasks to optimally use device resources (battery, CPU...). As a result, the feature that was working so far could misbehave on Q.

1) If AsnycTask is triggered when app was already in background, it could be restrcited by OS.

2) If AsyncTask triggered while app was in foreground but took too long to process, it could be restricted/killed by OS.

AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) [Src](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Error call stack with "rejectedExecution" hints me 1st case i.e. app was in background hence task was rejected for execution (as against cancelled in between).
To let a task run reliably while app is not in the foreground, recommended approach is to use Service class or its extended version e.g. IntentService based on task requirements. Hope it helps !

Comment: I'm downvoting this based on a lack of source for claims 1 and 2. I'm aware that the OS can terminate _entire apps_ due to resource pressure, but I don't believe the OS will selectively interfere with AsyncTasks (much less via a `StackOverflowException`, rather than something more explicit), without thorough coverage in the documentation. Additionally, the most recent (significant) background limitation changes that I am aware of were introduced in Oreo.